# Something like "ragtag group"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word/phrase that means "a team quickly put together from miscellaneous people".

It is NOT "ragtag group"/"motley crew".

I think it is "[something] team"

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/motley :  mixed, varied
disparate assorted conglomerate dappled diversified mingled  mixed variegated

Comment: @mplungjan I had already checked :) I'm afraid it's something a little more slangish

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ragtag : eclectic diverse sundry and many more

Comment: @mplungjan I had checked there too... no, it's not quite so literal as that. More like a colloquial, almost slangish, phrase.

Comment: Ah, ok. Please next time include your investigations - how about multitudinous

Comment: @mplungjan No...like "multitudinous team"? That's far too literal; and doesn't quite make sense IMHO.

Comment: In the context of a team for sports or other competition this might be called a 'scratch team'

Comment: @aPaulT You got it. Make it an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a team for sport or other competitions this could be called a 'scratch team'.

(answerfied comment)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more "official" sounding term you could try *[ad hoc](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ad+hoc)*:-

> for the special purpose or end presently under consideration: a
>   committee formed ad hoc to deal with the issue.